# Bacula over s3fs

Tags: debian, bacula, amazon-s3, s3fs, debian-lenny

We are constantly running out of space on our backup server so I want to move the backups to S3. Does it make sense to run Bacula on top of s3fs? Does anybody have experience with that? Is it reliable? What about bandwidth use? Can I expect s3fs to work nicely on Debian 5.0?

Answer (score 2):

theres no reason why s3fs won't work reliably under debian 5 that I'm aware of.

Re bandwidth, you need to understand that your backups may run a lot slower, they can only run as fast as the bandwidth you have to amazon because everything is pushed over the internet to S3. On this basis you need to carefully consider your data volume being backed up, the bandwidth you have available and consider whether this is going to exceed the window you have available to conduct your backups in.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer [S3QL](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/) over S3FS. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/wiki/other_s3_filesystems)'s a great feature comparison table (made by S3QL, so it is biased).

If you are at all concerned about bandwith, S3QL's compression and de-duplication are certainly advantages.

Answer (score 0):

s3fs developer here :)

> Can I expect s3fs to work nicely on Debian 5.0

Yes, I primarily develop under Debian (now squeeze)

Bandwidth use will be *slightly* higher than something such as FTP due to the HTTP overhead. As ccame mentioned, it's limited to your server's upstream bandwidth. I've benchmarked s3fs from EC2 instances at rates over 100mb/s